# In Magento 2.3, Is possible to cancel the Holded order?

Tags: magento2.3, orders, cancel-orders

In magento 2.3, Is possible to cancel the holded status order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mageto2, you ***can not cancel an order which is at Hold status.***

If you want then you first need to changes order status to **UnHold** then you can cancel.